# How to set UIKeyboardType for custom UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uikeyboardtype

I have implemented a custom control, which is a subclass of `UIView` and conforms to the protocol `<UIKeyInput>` to read the Keyboard input.

The problem is, that I want to show a numerical Keyboard instead of the regular one and I don't know how.

Comment: are you working with keyboard extension or what..? if there is only view  then what need of keyboard. unclear your question.

Comment: As stated in the question it is a **subclass** of `UIView` and conforms to `UIKeyInput` (It takes input)

Comment: check this:http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2011/May/msg00926.html